# Relationship between student, enrollment, course and section table

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, relational-database

I want to get record **student** enroll the specific **course** in which **section** ???
Because one course taught in multiple sections.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :enrolments
    has_many :courses, through: :enrolment
end
class course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :enrolment
    has_many :students, through: :enrolment
    has_many :sections
end
class enrolment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :students
    belongs_to :courses
end
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :courses
end
```

**Relationship**

```
Student.first.courses.first.sections
```

Due to this relationship i got multiple sections.
  But I want to get single **section** in which **student** enroll the specific **course** ???
   Here I am confused do you think this design is good? If not please provide some suggestions.

Comment: Please tell us under what conditions a row/record goes into each table/class. Your design does not appear to contain the data you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table/class with (student, course, section) where a articular student is enrolled in particular section of a particular course, or with (enrolment, section) where a pair satisfies the relationship when the enrolment student is enrolled in the enrolment section--which from your remarks is probably not how you are using the enrolment & sections of class Class. (Ask yourself: how would you *record* that a particular student is enrolled in a particular section of a course?) Start with Student, Class & Section; add Enrolled with student-course-section.

Comment: Without the create the table/class, its work fine by adding the relationship between table/section and table/enrollment, 
Section <----[1:M]----> Enrollment

Comment: It's hard to understand your comment. (Also, I was using "/" between relational & orm concepts, ie table/class, row/record & column/field.) I guess you are saying that you are suggesting a third choice of how to change the design. I guess you are saying that your addition didn't add a table. But there are three ways to add that 1:M and all three leave you with a table/class with an enrollment-section column/field pair. per my answer.

Comment: Yes by create a relationship between Section and Enrollment,         Section <----[1:M]----> Enrollment.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think could work based on Laravel framework.

**Tables**

- Students
- Courses
- Sections

**Table Representation**

Students Table

`id | name | email |
---|------|-------|
1  |Test  |test@test.com|`

Courses Table

`id | name |
---|------|
1  |Course A|`

Sections Table

`id | name |
---|------|
1  |Section A|`

**Relationships**

- Students <----[M:M]----> Courses
- Courses <----[M:M]----> Sections

**Relationship Tables**

- Course_Student - course_id & student_id(PK & FK)
- Course_Section - course_id & section_id(PK & FK)

Course_Student Table

`course_id | student_id|
----------|-----------|
1         |1`

Course_Section Table

`course_id | section_id
----------|-----------
1         |1`

Now you can get student_id, course_id and section_id based on Weak entities or Intermediate tables(as per Laravel).

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks for reply. But how we get the specific **section** in which student enroll the specific course ??? e.g programing course taught in section A,B and C. Student enroll the programing course in section A. How we get the the Section A in which student enroll the course??? Because right now student get the multiple section A,B and C. through this query 'Student.first.courses.first.sections'